# Yablo's condition on "Truth about a subject matter"

Tags: philosophy-of-language, modal-logic, philosophy-of-logic

In section 2.4 of "Aboutness" Yablo offers the following analysis of what does it mean that a statament is true about a certain subject matter/topic:

> So, what is the proposition we are speaking of when we speak of “what
> A says about m”? It’s a proposition that is true, we said, just if A
> is true about m. For A to be true about m means that A, should it be
> false, is at any rate not false because of how matters stand with
> respect to m. This admits of a simple test: A is true about m iff one
> can make A true outright without changing how matters stand where m is
> concerned.
>
> **6 A is true about m in w iff A is true simpliciter in a world m-equivalent to w**

> Truth about m, considered as a modality, is possibility-like: A is
> true about m in w just if it could be true, for all that w’s
> m-condition has to say about it.

I am not sure that **6** would be a correct way of expressing formally that a statament is true about the subject matter **m** iff in another world it was possibile for that statament to be true, i.e. that the condition concerned with the subject matter **m** permits the statament to be true.

For instance, we can suppose that stataments such as "the numebr of planets = 8" presupposes the existence of certain abstract objects, numbers, in order to be true. Suppose that our world is numberless. Then the statament, according to Yablo, would still be true regarding **concrete things that exist**.

This is because, following Yablo's reasoning, the condition concerned with **concreta** does not prevent that in a world numbers exist, and so "the number of planets=8" is true in the real world because **there could be a world equivalent to ours for the concreta in which the numbers exist.**

But the statament I have just highlighted is not too strong, I think, to allow us to imply that then THERE IS a world in which "the number of planets=8" is true. For sure, there *could* be a world in which it is true given the fact that that world is equivalent for **concreta** to our.

But if we were to use the criterion expressed in 6 to identify if a statament is true about a certain subject matter, we could end up with a different conclusion for "the number of planets=8 is true about **concreta**" if we assuemd that the existence of number is metaphisically impossibile.

Suppose numbers exist in no possible worlds, they are metaphysically impossibile. Then, even though we would like to say that "the number of planets=8" is true about **concreta**, following the **6**, we wouldn't be able to do so, because there would not be worlds equivalent to our world for **concreta** in which the statament "the numbers of planet = 8" is true and this is caused by the fact that there can't be world with numbers in it, because that is metaphysically impossibile.
So we would end up with violating the condition **6** for the sm **concreta** and we would have to say that "the number of planets=8" is not true about **concreta**, and we would not like to reach this conclusion.

Is there anything I misunderstood from "Aboutness" that would clear up this point or am I correct in having identified a problem with the condition **6**, namely that it is not a good "formal criterion" for "A is true about **m** if it could have been true regardless of how things stand **m**-wise?

Comment: Yablo is just assuming that there is a *possible* world where numbers exists. This is equivalent to what you say: "there could be a world equivalent to ours for the concreta in which the numbers exist." The "could" there is what makes the worlds merely possible. You agree with him, I think.